# Logic in Computer Science - Define inclusive XOR by induction

Tags: logic, induction, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

What is the formal definition by induction for iterated exclusive or (XOR) from $i = 1$ to $n$. Thanks

This is the notation: $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n A_i$.

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (i.e. LaTeX commands) for mathematical notaitons.

Comment: What do you want to define? The formula $\bigoplus_{i=2}^n A_i$ or its truth table?

Comment: The formula, except from i = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We define by induction of $n \geq 1$ the formula $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n A_i$ (given the formulas $A_1, \dots, A_n$):

- Base case ($n = 1$): $\bigoplus_{i=1}^1 A_i := A_1$.
- Inductive step: $\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n+1} A_i := (\bigoplus_{i=1}^n A_i) \oplus A_{n+1}$, where the second occurrence of $\oplus$ is the usual binary XOR operator.

Note that, since the binary $\oplus$ is associative, the inductive step can equivalently be defined as:

- Inductive step: $\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n+1} A_i := A_{1} \oplus (\bigoplus_{i=2}^{n+1} A_i) $.

Apart from the syntactical definition of $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n A_i$, its semantics is: $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n A_i$ is true if and only if an odd number of the $A_i$'s are true.

Comment: The semantics you claim in the last paragraph **does not agree with** your recursive definition. The recursive definition makes $\bigoplus_i A_i$ true if and only if _an odd number_ of the $A_i$s are true.

Comment: Are you sure that it's true when exact one of the terms is true? I would have thought it would be when an odd number of terms is true, that is 1+1+1=1

Comment: @HenningMakholm - Of course, you're right! I fixed it, thank you.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco thank you! I was having trouble defining this with the notations

Comment: It is probably worth noting that there is nothing special about $\oplus$ happening here. This recursive definition works for any associative binary operation, e.g. $+$ and $\sum$. We can further extend it to the $n=0$ case if that operation has a unit which $\oplus$ does, namely falsity/$0$.